# browser caching feature vs asp.net caching feature

Tags: browser-cache, asp.net-caching

by default browsers will cache the static files like image, js and css files. And it also cache http get request. If this feature is already there, then why we need asp.net output caching feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net caching is for creating the output sent to multiple clients the browser cache is a single client caching for itself.

Asp.net caching can cache individual parts of a larger output and jsut change the bits that are required to service a particualr client. e.g. changing the greeting at the top of the page, or making the "Top sellers" region relative.